Passenger to airline staff: "I meant that about dinner."
A passenger misses her flight, but the next one is full. So, she waits in case someone may cancel their ticket in the next flight. She says:
If you get a seat, it is dinner for everyone.
Then someone finally cancels a ticket. When she is talking to the staff at the desk, she says:
I meant that about dinner, you know. Late Passenger (see: 9:22 - 9:38)
By saying "I meant that about dinner", does she mean "I was serious about my offer that I would buy you each a dinner?"

Yes, that is what she means.

It could be seen as a clarifying expansion of "I meant that." Since some time has passed, one might say "meant what?" It can be understood simply as equivalent to "I meant [what I said] about dinner."

@AndyBonner, Very good explanation. It just snapped in.

Yes.  She means "I was serious about my offer that I would buy you each dinner."
"I meant that about dinner, you know."
"that" -- points to (has an antecedent of) her statement "If you get a seat, it is dinner for everyone."
"for dinner" -- clarifies or emphasizes that "that" refers to her statement about dinner not some other statement.
"you know" -- a tag for emphasis like the British "innit"

You might want to add: [Pronoun or person] meant [something] means to be serious about some situation or offer.
